# Mock listener lambda kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

Please help, I have a question about how I can do a unit test for the following class:

```
class MovieInteractor constructor(
        private val movieService: MovieService
) : MovieContracts.IMovieInteractor {

    override fun find(year: String) {
        movieService
                .onSuccess { year, genre ->
                    mListener!!.onSuccessFindMovie(title, genre)
                }
                .onError {
                    mListener!!.onError(it)
                }
                .find(year)
    }

}
```

I am using Mockito to MovieService mock, also listener mock.
This is the class to provide service

```
class MovieServiceImpl constructor() : MovieService {

    private var mSuccess: ((String, String) -> Unit)? = null
    private var mError: ((String) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun onSuccess(success: (String, String) -> Unit): MovieService {
        this.mSuccess = success
        return this
    }

    override fun onError(error: (String) -> Unit): MovieService {
        this.mError = error
        return this
    }

    override fun find(year: String) {
        // some logic
        if(something) {
            mSuccess?.invoke("title", "genre")
        } else {
            mError?.invoke("error")
        }
    }
}
```

I test my interactor with mockito

```
    @Mock
    lateinit var mServiceMock: MovieService

    lateinit var mInteractor: MovieContracts.IMovieInteractor

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mInteractor = MovieInteractor(mServiceMock)
    }


    @Test
    fun `should get success response`() {
       // I don't know if i need to use when, doAnswer, doNothing or something else
       whenever(mServiceMock.find("some-data"))
            .thenReturn()

        val data = mInteractor.find("2020")
        assertNotNull(data)
    
    }
```

This produce me java.lang.NullPointerException on MovieInteractor onError method

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `!!` on objects that can be null, use the safe-call operator `?` instead. Then the `mSuccess` and `mError` listener get only called when they are not null:

```
override fun find(year: String) {
        if(something) {
            mSuccess?.invoke("title", "genre")
        } else {
            mError?.invoke("error")
        }
    }

// ...

    override fun find(year: String) {
        movieService
                .onSuccess { year, genre ->
                    mListener?.onSuccessFindMovie(title, genre)
                }
                .onError {
                    mListener?.onError(it)
                }
                .find(year)
    }
```